# How to combine filtering and pagination in Django?

Tags: python, django, filter, pagination

I am new programming with Python. I want to combine paginations with filter but the solutions that I find do not work for me. This is my view

views.py

```
@login_required
def publication_list(request):
    f = PublicationFilter(request.GET, queryset=Publication.objects.all())

    return render(request, 'info/filter.html', {'filter':f})
```

filter.py

```
from registration.models import Publication
import django_filters





class PublicationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    user__username = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='Nombre de usuario')
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='Titulo')


    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = [
        'user__username', 'title', 'estatus',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to implement pagination code like  [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html).

You would just change the first line to use `.filter()` instead of `.all()`, and the rest would stay the same.